# Scenario Outline without examples - Cucumber

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, integration-testing, gherkin

Does `Scenrio outline` works without `Examples` and just a table in every tool or Intellij is the special one?

I read the Gherkin reference and it specifies that a `Scenario outline must have an Examples` below it.

`https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/`

But when I run my tests using `Scenario Outline` it works fine without the `Examples` section anywhere. Here:

```
Scenario Outline: Sequence of customer update for something
  Given we create a Customer 
  When we update the customer with a state "<name>"
      Then the response status code is 200
        And we close the response

        | name|
        | Bob|
        | Adam|
        | Rachel|
```

How is that working?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's interpreting the table as a [Cucumber Data Table](https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/#data-tables), which looks similar to an Example table but behaves differently.  Example tables cause the entire scenario to re-run for each row, but Data Tables are just a large, single parameter passed into the step immediately above them.

I am a little surprised that you didn't get a syntax error for omitting the `Examples:` keyword though.  I just tried removing the `Examples:` on one of the Scenario Outlines in my environment, and while it did "pass" (or rather, didn't fail), it didn't actually run the test (the report shows 0 scenarios, 0 steps).  So beware, you may have a false positive on your hands.

I went to file a bug actually, and found that [it has already been filed](https://github.com/cucumber-attic/gherkin2/issues/28). *Ten years ago...*

Comment: It is not the data table as the argument  in the Java code for the when part of the scenario outline is String and not the Data Table object. I thought it will barf but to my surprise it didn't and it is running the scenarios perfectly

Comment: Huh, that's interesting.  I guess cucumber java is smart enough to handle that situation and just forge ahead.  I'm actually using cucumber.js, and it doesn't barf, but it doesn't run anything either.

Comment: In my case it doesn't barf but runs the scenarios which is kinda weird

Answer (score 0):

In my case I falsely had a Scenario Outline without examples at all:

```
Scenario Outline: System displays search criteria
    Given UserS is logged in 
    Then UserS is on the 'Search' page
    When UserS clicks on the 'Search criteria' link
    Then the system displays the search criteria
```

Tests weirdly run all the way completing without errors. It was only when I tried to create an html report that a bug kept saying that examples did not exist, which led us to check the feature file.

So my guess is the tests somehow bypass the Examples section, if there is no parameter present, but the reporter is not that lenient.